# Viewport height to large in landscape

Tags: viewport

I have a rectangular website with navigation buttons on the bottom. When viewing the website in landscape mode the bottom and navigation gets cut off, not visible.. How can I make it vertically centered in landscape mode?

My container:

```
#container {
height: 500px;
width: 910px;
margin-right: -200px;
margin-left: -450px;
position: fixed;
top: 20%;
left: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines, but work only in new browsers. [Here is idea](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html)

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Neiiic but if I do it like that the top of my rectangle gets cut off instead. The only thing close to what I'm looking for was this viewport:    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.7, maximum-scale=0.7"> But then it doesn't upsize in landscape mode.